# Moodle adds tags to email body, subject and sender's name

Tags: email, moodle

I installed Moodle for Windows (version Moodle 4.2.1+)/ Then I sent some emails from site, subject of the messages was surrounded with "tags"  and , sender's name was surrounded with "tags"  and . The plain text message body was between "tags"  and , though html message body was okay.
It looks like on screenshot.

[image]

I have no idea, what is behind the problem. I've installed earlier versions of Moodle before and I've never encountered this problem. I would really appreciate, if I could get a direction to search for the problem cause.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally switched to *Yes* setting *Show template information* in *Site administration>Development>Debugging*, so information about the email templates was shown.

Found out by loading the Moodle folder to Notepad++ as a project and searching in files for a string '<!-- template(PHP)'. This string is in one file *\server\moodle\lib\classes\output\mustache_filesystem_loader.php* only and *$CFG->debugtemplateinfo* appears in the same function that contains this string. So I checked settings for *Debugging* and switched *Show template information* to *No*. Now emails do not contain any additional strings.